How can I read a WMTS into R Leaflet?
I want to load a WMTS into R Leaflet.
I've tried a number of variations on the file pathway, and also tried "addWMSTiles()" but so far nothing loads into the Leaflet map. I can load in the data as a WMS by adjusting the file path and using "addWMSTiles" but then the file loading is too slowly for effective web mapping.
library(sf)
library(leaflet)

# Define the WMTS URL
wmts_url_template <- "https://geo.spatialhub.scot/geoserver/ext_rpth/gwc/service/wmts/rest?authkey=b85aa063-d598-4582-8e45-e7e6048718fc/pub_rpth/default/EPSG:3857/{TileMatrix}/{TileRow}/{TileCol}?format=image/png"

# Create a basic leaflet map
map <- leaflet() %>%
    addTiles() %>%
    addTiles(
       urlTemplate = wmts_url_template,  # Add the WMTS layer
       options = tileOptions(opacity = 0.7)  # Adjust opacity
       ) %>%
    setView(lng = -3.5, lat = 55.5, zoom = 6)  # Set the initial view

# View the map
map

# alternative url I tried: "https://geo.spatialhub.scot/geoserver/ext_rpth/gwc/service/wmts?SERVICE=WMTS&VERSION=1.0.0&REQUEST=GetTile&LAYER=pub_rpth&STYLE=generic_blue&TILEMATRIXSET=EPSG:3857&TILEMATRIX={z}&TILEROW={y}&TILECOL={x}&FORMAT=image/png&authkey=b85aa063-d598-4582-8e45-e7e6048718fc" 


I found a solution to reading in this data was WMTS from geoserver:
library(leaflet)
library(dplyr)

leaflet() %>%
# Set initial map view
setView(lng = -4, lat = 57, zoom = 7) %>%
# Add WMS Tiles as an overlay group
addWMSTiles(
  baseUrl = "https://geo.spatialhub.scot/geoserver/ows?authkey=b85aa063-d598-4582-8e45-e7e6048718fc",
  layers = "ext_rpth:pub_rpth",
  options = WMSTileOptions(format = "image/png", transparent = TRUE),
  attribution = "XXX",
  group = "Paths"
)

